# convert factor levels in one column to column names

Tags: r, levels

this is my dataset smaple

```
label       text
location    thyroid
symptoms    Depression
location    thyroid
name of disease hypothyroidism
location    thyroid
location    thyroid
```

the code i tried in r

```
library(readr)
notes <- read_csv("some.csv")
notes$label <- as.factor(notes$label) # convert title to factor
dim(notes)[1]*(0.7)
table(notes$label)
t <- transpose(notes)
```

output in console

```
          > table(notes$label)

            causes         location  name of disease serious symptoms 
             8               73               54               12 
            symptoms 
              102 


    writers_matrix <- as.matrix(notes)
    ta <- t(writers_matrix)
    ta <- as.data.frame(ta)
```

Result got:

I get 2 obs of 249 variables just like a wide table instead I want to 
extract the levels in 'label' columns as column names and produce a 
new data frame with five columns since there are 5 levels and group values of those levels under each column as row values

Comment: Please add an expected output.

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: I want the table with column names as causes, location, name of disease serious symptoms, symptoms and their corresponding values from the original dataframe @ Richard

Comment: when i get the factor level of column 'label' i get 5 levels but i want these levels as names of new columns...just like a transpose but a more aggregated /combined dataframe

Comment: Please **show** the expected output

Comment: column names ---> Name of disease  | causes | location | symptoms | serious symptoms
                                row names ----->  Addison's Disease | overproduction of growth hormones | thyroid | depression | sleep disturbances